# How do I extend the Elasticsearch SSL Certificate expiry periods?

Tags: elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5, elk

I have an ES Cluster(ES version 7.4.2) that has been running for 3 years.
when I run the following query.

`GET _ssl/certificates`

I'm getting the output.

`"expiry" : "2022-11-20T07:27:29.000Z"`

in `/usr/share/elasticsearch`
For the new '`temescls01-ca.p12`' certificate
I run '`./bin/elasticsearch-certutil cert --ca /etc/elasticsearch/certs/temescls01-ca.p12`' and when I enter the '`CA CERT password`' it generates a new temescl01-ca.p12 certificate.

For the new '`temescls01-certificates.p12`' certificate
I run '`./bin/elasticsearch-certutil cert /etc/elasticsearch/certs/temescls01-certificates.p12`' and enter the '`keystore password`'.

I'm using the old certificates' passwords for both new certificates.

I was able to create all 2 certificates. But when I stop the elasticsearch service and replace the old certificates with new certificates [by following the document here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/update-node-certs-same.html), the node cannot join the cluster. When I replace the old certificate, the node joins the cluster without any problems.

An example from elasticsearch.yml

> elasticsearch.yml
>
> xpack.security.enabled: true
> xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled: true
> xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode: certificate
> xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.path: certs/temescls01-certificates.p12
> xpack.security.transport.ssl.keystore.password: XXXXXXXXX
> xpack.security.transport.ssl.truestore.path: certs/temescls01-certificates.p12
> xpack.security.transport.ssl.truestore.password: XXXXXXXXX

Is there something i did wrong?

Comment: You followed the wrong document. The document you shared for the same CA certificate. But you generated a new "CA" certificate.
You can follow this one https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/update-node-certs-different.html

Comment: Do you have an old CA certificate?
If yes can you please check the expiry date of that certificate?
openssl pkcs12 -in elastic-certificates.p12 -nokeys | openssl x509 -noout -enddate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s not possible to extend the expiry date of a certificate. But you can create a new one. If you are using PKCS #12 format of SSL/TLS (p12) certificate you can use this article to create a new certificate.

https://medium.com/p/99820ff87615